# Django - In Memory Channels Layers vs Heroku Redis

Tags: django, heroku, websocket, redis

Considering adding some push notifications to a web app built with Django hosted on Heroku.

I am pondering the pros and cons of `InMemoryChannelLayer` vs `Heroku Redis`.

'Heroku & Redis' seems is a better option for scalability. But budget is limited, so `InMemoryChannelLayer`have a better appeal right now!

The use of the app is limited to a few users to measure a few things, and probably wouldn't require full scalability option at this stage.

On the scalability front however, wondering what sort of `scalability` people refer to?

I saw that in-memory storage is not suitable for application with high traffic or large number of users at the same time and can consume a significant amount of memory causing potential performance issues.

I am wondering at what sort of level of use am I likely to run into this sort of problem? Are we talking 1000 users at the same time? 100? 10?

EDIT - Obviously, I am assuming I cannot use Redis without paying for the addon. If I am wrong, that would be a good argument in favour of Redis :)